# jQuery serialized data and PHP $_POST don't match

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I've got a page with a form.
This form has different 'sheets', while the user walks through these sheets information is called from a website using `$.ajax`, and the form gets dynamically added inputs.

At the very end I'm trying to post this form data to a PHP file.

I won't dump my whole code, since it's a lot of rules. But this is the part that I use to post:

```
function postForm() {
    ...
    var data = $('form.feedForm').serialize();
    //console.log( data );      
    $.post('.../get.php?feed_add_save_feeding', data )
    .fail( function() {
        console.log('fail');
        ...
    })
    .success( function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
        ...
    })
}
```

In my PHP I've added this, to see what comes through:

```
print_r( $_POST );
```

Looking in my console, I see that these parameters are post:

```
dateType              now
date_d                30
date_m                1
date_y                2016
time_h                19
time_m                27
time_s                42
herd_num_animals      150
herd                  85
menu                  26
feedtype_total_value  3639
tWeight               3639
weightCumu            3637
supps_name[29]        Test voer 1
supps_price[29]       128
supps_dry_weight[29]  94
supps_weight[29]      1837
supps_name[34]        Test voer 6
supps_price[34]       18
supps_dry_weight[34]  70
supps_weight[34]      1800
supps_name[30]        Test voer 2
supps_price[30]       160
supps_dry_weight[30]  50
supps_weight[30]      1
user_id               1
```

The output in PHP is

```
Array
(
    [dateType] => now
    [date_d] => 30
    [date_m] => 1
    [date_y] => 2016
    [time_h] => 19
    [time_m] => 27
    [time_s] => 42
    [herd_num_animals] => 150
    [herd] => 85
    [menu] => 26
    [feedtype_total_value] => 3639
    [tWeight] => 3639
    [weightCumu] => 3637
    [supps_name] => Test voer 6
    [supps_price] => 18
    [supps_dry_weight] => 70
    [supps_weight] => 1837
)
```

Why don't all the submitted inputs come through in the PHP??

<sup>(Note: I left my code out on purpose, because of the size. If I should add some, or all of it, please leave a comment)</sup>

## EDIT

Here is the complete JS code and rendered HTML (copied from Firebug):

[JSFiddle (just the code, not a working demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/guzboyfv/1/)

Comment: When you say `console`, is that the network tab you're referring to?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer The console inside firebug

Comment: And what about the PHP process? Do you ever try to loop over all the data instead of just using the `print_r`. Usually it did't showing up on page by using `print_r` but data do exist in variable

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali using `foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) { echo $key.': '.$value."\n"; }` gives the exact same result.

Comment: what does `different 'sheets'` mean?

Comment: Do you name your elements like `<input type="text" name="supps_name[]">` or like  `<input type="text" name="supps_name">` ?

Comment: Most likely this is caused by your php settings which restrict number of fields

Comment: variables sent like `supps_name[29]`  will be arrays in php $_POST  == `$_POST['supps_name'][29]`

Comment: @hindmost not likely with this few params

Comment: @charlietfl and if the OP named them all like `name="supps_name"` it would collapse all the duplicated keys into one param taking the last encountered value, right?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes it will be an array. But using `print_r( $_POST)` should also display multidimensional arrays

Comment: @DelightedD0D I believe so ... and serialization wouldn't show `[]`

Comment: @LinkinTED that is a bit confusing ... you need `[]` in html names if they duplicate ... html not shown

Comment: @charlietfl, yes there a supps added dynamically they look like this `<input type="text" name="supps_price[29]" value="128">` (from the firebug console)

Comment: are you using any php framework? or is this straight php. Seems very strange unless something else is modifying `$_POST` like in a  loop

Comment: I've added the complete JS code and rendered(!!) HTML (copied from Firebug after walking all the sheets). @charlietfl, no I don't use any php framework.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, the `id` of the supplement is added, for example `supps_price[29]` or `supps_price[54]`

Comment: Can we see your php script? this should work as expected given the code youve shown see http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/dupenames/index.php and view the console

Comment: @DelightedD0D, sure: https://jsfiddle.net/guzboyfv/2/ I've added it in the CSS part (note that I use a class for the mysqli queries)

Comment: Hmm, Im a bit confused, in that code you have `$get = array_keys($_GET); $action = ( isset($get[0] ) ) ? $get[0] : '';` then you use `$action` in a switch statement, but your request to this script is a POST request. That code shouldnt print anything at all, are you sure this is the code you have?

Comment: In this file I handle all requests. By posting to `get.php?feed_add_save_feeding` the page decides with case of the switch to take. The confusion is logical, it's a large amount of code on different platforms, that makes it also hard to track down the error.

Comment: I dont think you understand, that code would not work. You're making a `POST` request, but you are checking for the first `GET` variable to exist and be the string `'feed_add_save_feeding'` ....it wont be, there wont be any GET variables, you sent a POST request, ........unless you're doing something weird that you're not showing us like `$_GET = $_POST;` and I cant imagine why you would do that....

Comment: @DelightedD0D, I took the code that should post the data into the database and paste in into a separate file. Gives me the same error. It looks like it's a jQuery problem...

Comment: Im not so sure, the code you showed would not have printed anything at all, so, since you were getting stuff printed, some other part of your code must have been printing it, I dont see how this issue could be related to the client side, my example shows that that part works as does your own excerpt from the console showing the sent data

Comment: @DelightedD0D, it works for all the other cases inside get.php. However changing the POST to a GET, does seem to do the trick. Thanks for all the help to all of you

Comment: Your other requests must be `GET` requests then ;) , glad you got it sorted, or, you have some unshown code that does something like `$_GET = $_POST;` but in some way that removes the nested arrays, and if thats the case, id track that code down and remove it because it will very likely bite you again down the road.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, that's the crazy/ funny thing. They do work with a GET/ POST combination

Comment: Then definitely check for something  like `$_GET = $_POST;` somewhere in your other code, it must be there somewhere if that is happening unless your other requests to `get.php` are correctly using `GET` requests

Comment: @DelightedD0D I stripped down my get.php file to the PHP code I provided in https://jsfiddle.net/guzboyfv/2/ With that code, the same error showed. So it beats me... Don't know why it doesn't work. And looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259421/post-and-get-in-the-same-ajax-request it should work to combine the both.

Comment: That post doesnt say what you think in does. It says "You can access any regular query string parameters in the $_GET array, or in your case, parse it out of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. The POST ed data will be in $_POST as expected."  This is saying that parameters provided like `http://mysite.php?someKey=someValue` or via a `GET` request are available in the `$_GET` array while posted values are available in the `$_POST` array. This is reiterated by a commenter with "You can access POST data using $_POST array and GET data using $_GET"

Comment: You must have code in `class.db.php` or `class.user.php` that is copying some of the keys from $_POST to $_GET they do not naturally contain any of the same values

Comment: Nope, sending the post data to a file that only contains `print_r($_POST)` has the same. Not all data comes through.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is you are sending several arrays and the correct array keys are shown in the output

variables sent in post body like `supps_name[29]` will be arrays in php

```
is_array($_POST['supps_name'])// true
```

Your html inputs should look like

```
<input name="supps_name[]">
```

OR with defined keys

```
<input name="supps_name[1]">
```

Comment: I used `var_dump($_POST['supps_name']`, it gives me `string(11) "Test voer 6"`... where it indeed should be an array.